# C++ pointer to class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, function-pointers

I want to do something like this:

```
struct CLI_Command{
    CLI_Command(char* s, void (*h)(void)){
        command_string = s;
        handler = h;
    }

    char* command_string;
    void (*handler)(void);
};

class CLI  {
    public:
        CLI();

    private:
        CLI_Command cli_table[NO_CLI_COMMANDS] = {
                CLI_Command("Command1",   handler1),
                CLI_Command("Command2",   handler2)
        };

        void handler1(){};
        void handler2(){};
};
```

I know that I need something similar to CLI::*handler, but I can't get the syntax right. I keep running into errors like this:

```
"error: no matching function for call to 'CLI_Command::CLI_Command(const char [4], <unresolved overloaded function type>)"
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to take the address of a non-static member function, which is disallowed.  I have [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25953204/1392132) a similar question recently. Maybe it will help you.  Note that modern C++ provides powerful tools to write your program much cleaner and safer.

Comment: @5gon12eder: It's perfectly legal to take the address of a non-static member function, but the result is a pointer-to-member, not a function pointer.

Comment: @5gon12eder OK, can you elaborate on these tools? Or point me in some direction? :) . I am making a command line interface through an UART on an embedded device.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that's of course correct.  So the disallowed thing is “taking the address of a non-static member function an use it as a function pointer”.

Comment: @Jolle For example, you could make your table a `std::map<std::string, Command>` where `Command` could be an appropriate `typedef` or – if you want more OO and can live with the overhead, create a `CommandInterface` and put polymorphic command objects in your map that you invoke virtual functions on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This illustrates the correct syntax:

```
class CLI;

struct CLI_Command
{
    CLI_Command(char* s, void (CLI::*h)(void))
    {
        command_string = s;
        handler = h;
    }

    char* command_string;
    void (CLI::*handler)(void);

    void raise( CLI* the_cli ) { return (the_cli->*handler)(); }
};

class CLI
{
    public:
        CLI();

    private:
        static CLI_Command cli_table[NO_CLI_COMMANDS];

        void handler1(){};
        void handler2(){};
};

CLI::CLI_Command cli_table[NO_CLI_COMMANDS] = {
  { "Command1",   &CLI::handler1 },
  { "Command2",   &CLI::handler2 }
};
```

Names of member functions do not decay to pointer-to-member.  You must use `&` explicitly, and a qualified name, when creating a pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers, another option is to use `std::function` together with `std::bind()`:

```
struct CLI_Command{
    ...
    std::function<void> handler;
};

class CLI {
    ...
    CLI_Command cli_table[NO_CLI_COMMANDS] = {
      { "Command1",   std::bind(&CLI::handler1, this) },
      { "Command2",   std::bind(&CLI::handler2, this) }
    };

    void handler1(){};
    void handler2(){};
};
```

Comment: Oh cool. Do you have an idea of how much overhead this will produce? My target is a little embedded device, so I can't afford to much overhead :) .

Comment: @Jolle no problem, this is for completeness so the question might be helpful to other people.

Comment: actually it was a question, because I have no idea if this will produce any overhead :)

Comment: Heh :) Actually it may bring some overhead depending on implementation, but on other hand it brings more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
void handler1(){}
void handler2(){}
```

are member functions of `CLI`. The correct way to "address to" them is `&CLI::handler1` and not `handler1`. However then, they won't be accepted by `void (*h)(void)`, which would need to be changed to `void (CLI::*h)(void)`. But that is probably not what you want.

Maybe consider reading about [`std::function`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for type erasure, or make your `handler1/handler2` static.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the syntax for a pointer to class member instead of the syntax for a loose function pointer.

```
class CLI;

struct CLI_Command{
    CLI_Command(char* s, void (CLI::*h)(void)){
        command_string = s;
        handler = h;
    }

    char* command_string;
    void (CLI::*handler)(void);
};
```

In addition, make sure you call the function through the pointer of the current CLI class;

```
void CLI::process(char *cmd) {
    CLI_Command command* = /* lookup the command */
    this->(command->handle)();
}
```

Comment: You need `->*` (or `.*`) when dealing with pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, make your methods `static`

```
static void handler1(){};
static void handler2(){};
```

Whatever consequences ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback/402385#402385) please, for more detailed info) this will have :-( .